How do I parse a date with no time?
How do I use parse_from_str to parse a date with no time.
I have tried various variations like this:
Let d = DateTime::parse_from_str(“12/Sep/2024”, “%d/%b/%Y”);

Let dad = DateTime::parse_from_str(“12/9/2024”, “%d/%m/%Y”);

But I keep getting a “not enough” error.

A DateTime obviously needs a time… what you want is a NaiveDate (assuming you use chrono which you should specify!)
